# how to get rid of the: let id = UUID() is Immutable error inside decodable struct

Tags: swift

Is there a way to fix the error:

```
Immutable property will not be decoded because it is declared with an initial value which cannot be overwritten
```

This error shows next to let id = UUID()
I know why it's there, but setting id to var doesn't work because JSONDecoder cannot decode the struct.
The program runs fine but the error is very annoying because there's 15 of them.
I'm somewhat new to swift so if there are any errors in this code feel free to critique them.

```
import Foundation

struct Ability: Codable, Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
struct Abilities: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let ability: Ability
    let is_hidden: Bool
    let slot: Int
}
struct Forms: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
struct Species: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
struct OfficialArtwork: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let front_default: String?
}
struct Other: Codable {
    //let dream_world: DreamWorld
    let art: OfficialArtwork
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
     
        case art = "official-artwork"
    }
}
struct Sprites: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let other: Other
}
struct Type: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
struct Types: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let type: Type
}
struct Stat: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
struct Stats: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let base_stat: Int
    let stat: Stat
    
}
struct Move: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
}
struct Moves: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var move: Move
}
struct APIInfo: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let abilities: [Abilities]
    let base_experience: Int
    let forms: [Forms]
    let height: Int
    //let held_items:
    let location_area_encounters: String
    let moves: [Moves]
    let name: String
    //let past_types:
    let species: Species
    let sprites: Sprites
    let stats: [Stats]
    let types: [Types]
    let weight: Int
}
struct Results: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String
}

struct Link: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let results: [Results]
}



class Data {
        func fetchName(completion: @escaping ([Results]) -> () ){
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=1118") else {return}
                
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
                    let jsonResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Link.self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completion(jsonResult.results)
                    }
                }.resume()
        }
        func fetchInfo(link: String, completion: @escaping (APIInfo) -> () ){
            
            guard let url = URL(string: link) else {
                print("error")
                return
            }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {data, response, error in
                let jsonResult = try! JSONDecoder().decode(APIInfo.self, from: data!)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(jsonResult)
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add CodingKeys and omit`id` for example

```
struct Ability: Codable, Identifiable{
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let url: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, url }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for all of the structs in my file though. For example some keys point to other structs and not all keys will be the same type.

Comment: Of course you have to add `CodingKeys` in all affected structs. The type of the keys is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay I just tried it and I must have misunderstood how CodingKey works. Thanks for your answer

Comment: `CodingKeys` have two major functions: To map keys to other keys and to exclude keys for constants and computed properties by omitting them.